# Optional keys in enum-based object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an enum:

```
enum ItemsEnum {
   First = 'first',
   Second = 'second',
   Third = 'third',
}
```

Now Im creating an object based on this enum:

```
const items: { [key in ItemsEnum]: string } = {
   [ItemsEnum.First]: 'some string',
   [ItemsEnum.Third]: 'another string',
                                        // error - missing ItemsEnum.Second
};
```

But now typescript will complain because `items` object is missing `ItemsEnum.Second`.

**Question**: is there a way to "pick" only two elements or anything else so the typescript doesnt complain if an object doesnt contain EVERY element from the enum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it thus:

```
enum ItemsEnum {
  First = 'first',
  Second = 'second',
  Third = 'third',
}
const items: { [key in ItemsEnum]?: string } = {
  [ItemsEnum.First]: 'some string',
  [ItemsEnum.Third]: 'another string',
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
const items: { [key : string]: string } = {
   [ItemsEnum.First]: 'some string',
   [ItemsEnum.Third]: 'another string',
};
```

if you use `key in ItemsEnum` you need to mention all members

Comment: So its not possible?

Comment: @marcopuchat as far as I know, not possible, and there is a reason behind it, in case your enum will be changed in future you should be getting compile error.